# C++ Am I using void functions incorrectly?

Tags: c++, function, void

Errors:

- C2182: 'tellStats' : illegal use of type 'void'
- C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'int'
- incomplete type is not allowed.

All of these errors are found on this line:

```
    //ClassPractice.cpp
    void tellStats(pick);
```

which calls...

```
    //Functions.h
    void tellStats(string);
```

which is defined as...

```
    //Functions.cpp
        void tellStats(string choice)
    {
        if (choice == "wizard")
            {
            cout << "These are the Wizard's stats:" << endl;
            cout << "Max HP: 80\nSpeed: 7\nAttack: 10" << endl;
            }
    }
```

I don't understand why I am getting these errors. I don't know why an int is even involved with the error. I see nothing referring to ints in these sections of code. I thought I was using 'void' correctly because I don't want to return a value with the function.

Comment: What is the type of `pick`? Have you included `string`?

Comment: Somewhere along the line you pass an `int` into `tellStats` instead of a `string`.

Comment: Did you mean to call the function? That's `tellStats(pick)`, without the `void`

Comment: When you are invoking tellStats(), you should not specify a return type.

The line in ClassPractice.cpp should be:

    tellStats(pick);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont call a function with the return type. Dont say:

```
void tellStats(pick);
```

just use `tellStats(pick);`.

Is that line the only place you call tellStats?

Comment: The OP's error message ("cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'int'") suggests that yes, `pick` really is a string.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem! Yes, that is the only place I called tellStats().

Answer (score 3):

The `int` is a red herring. For historical reasons, compilers internally often substitute `int` when they're missing a type. This normally shouldn't happen, but here you see this exposed because the compiler tried to continue after the first error. The compiler incorrectly guessed that you wanted to define a variable `tellStats` of type <strike>void</strike>`int` and initialize that variable with a string.